# SQL Server failover cluster installation fails on primary node

Tags: sql-server, clustering, failover, windows-server

I'm trying to install SQL Server 2014 fail-over cluster, but the installation fails with following log i have tried  a lot of things but without any success.. The installation failed with following log:

```
Overall summary:
  Final result:                  Failed: see details below
  Exit code (Decimal):           -2061893606
  Start time:                    2015-11-03 07:58:27
  End time:                      2015-11-03 08:16:29
  Requested action:              InstallFailoverCluster

Setup completed with required actions for features.
Troubleshooting information for those features:
  Next step for SQLEngine:       Use the following information to resolve the error, uninstall this feature, and then run the setup process again.
  Next step for DQ:              Use the following information to resolve the error, uninstall this feature, and then run the setup process again.
  Next step for FullText:        Use the following information to resolve the error, uninstall this feature, and then run the setup process again.
  Next step for Replication:     Use the following information to resolve the error, uninstall this feature, and then run the setup process again.


Cluster properties:
  Machine name: MSSQL_NODE1
  Product              Instance             Instance ID                    Feature                                  Language             Edition              Version         Clustered  Configured

  Machine name: MSSQL_NODE2
  Product              Instance             Instance ID                    Feature                                  Language             Edition              Version         Clustered  Configured

Machine Properties:
  Machine name:                  MSSQL_NODE1
  Machine processor count:       2
  OS version:                    Windows Server 2012
  OS service pack:               
  OS region:                     United States
  OS language:                   English (United States)
  OS architecture:               x64
  Process architecture:          64 Bit
  OS clustered:                  Yes

Product features discovered:
  Product              Instance             Instance ID                    Feature                                  Language             Edition              Version         Clustered  Configured

Package properties:
  Description:                   Microsoft SQL Server 2014 
  ProductName:                   SQL Server 2014
  Type:                          RTM
  Version:                       12
  SPLevel:                       0
  Installation location:         C:\Users\Administrator.ST1\Desktop\MSSQLinstall\x64\setup\
  Installation edition:          Enterprise

Product Update Status:
  None discovered.

User Input Settings:
  ACTION:                        InstallFailoverCluster
  AGTDOMAINGROUP:                <empty>
  AGTSVCACCOUNT:                 ST1\Administrator
  AGTSVCPASSWORD:                *****
  ASBACKUPDIR:                   Backup
  ASCOLLATION:                   Latin1_General_CI_AS
  ASCONFIGDIR:                   Config
  ASDATADIR:                     Data
  ASLOGDIR:                      Log
  ASPROVIDERMSOLAP:              1
  ASSERVERMODE:                  MULTIDIMENSIONAL
  ASSVCACCOUNT:                  <empty>
  ASSVCPASSWORD:                 <empty>
  ASSVCSTARTUPTYPE:              Automatic
  ASSYSADMINACCOUNTS:            <empty>
  ASTEMPDIR:                     Temp
  COMMFABRICENCRYPTION:          0
  COMMFABRICNETWORKLEVEL:        0
  COMMFABRICPORT:                0
  CONFIGURATIONFILE:             C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Setup Bootstrap\Log\20151103_075827\ConfigurationFile.ini
  ENU:                           true
  ERRORREPORTING:                true
  FAILOVERCLUSTERDISKS:          Cluster Disk 1, Cluster Disk 3
  FAILOVERCLUSTERGROUP:          SQL Server (MSSQLSERVER)
  FAILOVERCLUSTERIPADDRESSES:    IPv4;10.232.7.110;Cluster Network 2;255.255.254.0
  FAILOVERCLUSTERNETWORKNAME:    SRVSQLCL01
  FEATURES:                      SQLENGINE, REPLICATION, FULLTEXT, DQ, SSMS, ADV_SSMS
  FILESTREAMLEVEL:               0
  FILESTREAMSHARENAME:           <empty>
  FTSVCACCOUNT:                  NT Service\MSSQLFDLauncher
  FTSVCPASSWORD:                 <empty>
  HELP:                          false
  IACCEPTSQLSERVERLICENSETERMS:  true
  INDICATEPROGRESS:              false
  INSTALLSHAREDDIR:              C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\
  INSTALLSHAREDWOWDIR:           C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\
  INSTALLSQLDATADIR:             E:\ClusterStorage\Volume1\
  INSTANCEDIR:                   C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\
  INSTANCEID:                    MSSQLSERVER
  INSTANCENAME:                  MSSQLSERVER
  ISSVCACCOUNT:                  NT AUTHORITY\Network Service
  ISSVCPASSWORD:                 <empty>
  ISSVCSTARTUPTYPE:              Automatic
  MATRIXCMBRICKCOMMPORT:         0
  MATRIXCMSERVERNAME:            <empty>
  MATRIXNAME:                    <empty>
  PID:                           *****
  QUIET:                         false
  QUIETSIMPLE:                   false
  RSINSTALLMODE:                 DefaultNativeMode
  RSSHPINSTALLMODE:              DefaultSharePointMode
  RSSVCACCOUNT:                  <empty>
  RSSVCPASSWORD:                 <empty>
  RSSVCSTARTUPTYPE:              Automatic
  SAPWD:                         <empty>
  SECURITYMODE:                  <empty>
  SQLBACKUPDIR:                  <empty>
  SQLCOLLATION:                  SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
  SQLSVCACCOUNT:                 ST1\Administrator
  SQLSVCPASSWORD:                *****
  SQLSYSADMINACCOUNTS:           ST1\administrator
  SQLTEMPDBDIR:                  <empty>
  SQLTEMPDBLOGDIR:               <empty>
  SQLUSERDBDIR:                  <empty>
  SQLUSERDBLOGDIR:               <empty>
  SQMREPORTING:                  true
  UIMODE:                        Normal
  UpdateEnabled:                 true
  UpdateSource:                  MU
  USEMICROSOFTUPDATE:            true
  X86:                           false

  Configuration file:            C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Setup Bootstrap\Log\20151103_075827\ConfigurationFile.ini

Detailed results:
  Feature:                       Management Tools - Complete
  Status:                        Passed

  Feature:                       Management Tools - Basic
  Status:                        Passed

  Feature:                       Database Engine Services
  Status:                        Failed: see logs for details
  Reason for failure:            An error occurred during the setup process of the feature.
  Next Step:                     Use the following information to resolve the error, uninstall this feature, and then run the setup process again.
  Component name:                SQL Server Database Engine Services Instance Features
  Component error code:          0x851A001A
  Error description:             Wait on the Database Engine recovery handle failed. Check the SQL Server error log for potential causes.
  Error help link:               http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?LinkId=20476&ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&EvtSrc=setup.rll&EvtID=50000&ProdVer=12.0.2000.8&EvtType=0xD15B4EB2%400x4BDAF9BA%401306%4026&EvtType=0xD15B4EB2%400x4BDAF9BA%401306%4026

  Feature:                       Data Quality Services
  Status:                        Failed: see logs for details
  Reason for failure:            An error occurred for a dependency of the feature causing the setup process for the feature to fail.
  Next Step:                     Use the following information to resolve the error, uninstall this feature, and then run the setup process again.
  Component name:                SQL Server Database Engine Services Instance Features
  Component error code:          0x851A001A
  Error description:             Wait on the Database Engine recovery handle failed. Check the SQL Server error log for potential causes.
  Error help link:               http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?LinkId=20476&ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&EvtSrc=setup.rll&EvtID=50000&ProdVer=12.0.2000.8&EvtType=0xD15B4EB2%400x4BDAF9BA%401306%4026&EvtType=0xD15B4EB2%400x4BDAF9BA%401306%4026

  Feature:                       Full-Text and Semantic Extractions for Search
  Status:                        Failed: see logs for details
  Reason for failure:            An error occurred for a dependency of the feature causing the setup process for the feature to fail.
  Next Step:                     Use the following information to resolve the error, uninstall this feature, and then run the setup process again.
  Component name:                SQL Server Database Engine Services Instance Features
  Component error code:          0x851A001A
  Error description:             Wait on the Database Engine recovery handle failed. Check the SQL Server error log for potential causes.
  Error help link:               http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?LinkId=20476&ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&EvtSrc=setup.rll&EvtID=50000&ProdVer=12.0.2000.8&EvtType=0xD15B4EB2%400x4BDAF9BA%401306%4026&EvtType=0xD15B4EB2%400x4BDAF9BA%401306%4026

  Feature:                       SQL Server Replication
  Status:                        Failed: see logs for details
  Reason for failure:            An error occurred for a dependency of the feature causing the setup process for the feature to fail.
  Next Step:                     Use the following information to resolve the error, uninstall this feature, and then run the setup process again.
  Component name:                SQL Server Database Engine Services Instance Features
  Component error code:          0x851A001A
  Error description:             Wait on the Database Engine recovery handle failed. Check the SQL Server error log for potential causes.
  Error help link:               http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?LinkId=20476&ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&EvtSrc=setup.rll&EvtID=50000&ProdVer=12.0.2000.8&EvtType=0xD15B4EB2%400x4BDAF9BA%401306%4026&EvtType=0xD15B4EB2%400x4BDAF9BA%401306%4026

  Feature:                       SQL Browser
  Status:                        Passed

  Feature:                       SQL Writer
  Status:                        Passed

  Feature:                       SQL Client Connectivity
  Status:                        Passed

  Feature:                       SQL Client Connectivity SDK
  Status:                        Passed

  Feature:                       Setup Support Files
  Status:                        Passed

Rules with failures:

Global rules:

There are no scenario-specific rules.

Rules report file:               C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Setup Bootstrap\Log\20151103_075827\SystemConfigurationCheck_Report.htm
```

After another one installation...

```
2015-11-10 00:23:18.70 Server      Microsoft SQL Server 2014 - 12.0.4100.1 (X64) 
        Apr 20 2015 17:29:27 
        Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation
        Standard Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.3 <X64> (Build 9600: ) (Hypervisor)

2015-11-10 00:23:18.71 Server      UTC adjustment: -8:00
2015-11-10 00:23:18.71 Server      (c) Microsoft Corporation.
2015-11-10 00:23:18.71 Server      All rights reserved.
2015-11-10 00:23:18.71 Server      Server process ID is 140.
2015-11-10 00:23:18.71 Server      System Manufacturer: 'VMware, Inc.', System Model: 'VMware Virtual Platform'.
2015-11-10 00:23:18.71 Server      Authentication mode is WINDOWS-ONLY.
2015-11-10 00:23:18.71 Server      Logging SQL Server messages in file 'F:\MSSQL12.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Log\ERRORLOG'.
2015-11-10 00:23:18.71 Server      The service account is 'ST1\Administrator'. This is an informational message; no user action is required.
2015-11-10 00:23:18.71 Server      Registry startup parameters: 
     -d F:\MSSQL12.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\master.mdf
     -e F:\MSSQL12.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Log\ERRORLOG
     -l F:\MSSQL12.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\mastlog.ldf
2015-11-10 00:23:18.71 Server      Command Line Startup Parameters:
     -s "MSSQLSERVER"
2015-11-10 00:23:19.06 Server      SQL Server detected 2 sockets with 1 cores per socket and 1 logical processors per socket, 2 total logical processors; using 2 logical processors based on SQL Server licensing. This is an informational message; no user action is required.
2015-11-10 00:23:19.06 Server      SQL Server is starting at normal priority base (=7). This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
2015-11-10 00:23:19.06 Server      Detected 3071 MB of RAM. This is an informational message; no user action is required.
2015-11-10 00:23:19.06 Server      Using conventional memory in the memory manager.
2015-11-10 00:23:19.21 Server      Default collation: SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS (us_english 1033)
2015-11-10 00:23:19.30 Server      The maximum number of dedicated administrator connections for this instance is '1'
2015-11-10 00:23:19.30 Server      This instance of SQL Server last reported using a process ID of 3260 at 11/9/2015 9:47:15 AM (local) 11/9/2015 5:47:15 PM (UTC). This is an informational message only; no user action is required.
2015-11-10 00:23:19.30 Server      Node configuration: node 0: CPU mask: 0x0000000000000003:0 Active CPU mask: 0x0000000000000003:0. This message provides a description of the NUMA configuration for this computer. This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
2015-11-10 00:23:19.32 Server      Using dynamic lock allocation.  Initial allocation of 2500 Lock blocks and 5000 Lock Owner blocks per node.  This is an informational message only.  No user action is required.
2015-11-10 00:23:19.36 spid7s      Starting up database 'master'.
2015-11-10 00:23:19.39 spid7s      There have been 256 misaligned log IOs which required falling back to synchronous IO.  The current IO is on file F:\MSSQL12.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\master.mdf.
2015-11-10 00:23:19.41 spid7s      11/10/15 00:23:19 Stack Overflow Dump not possible - Exception c00000fd EXCEPTION_STACK_OVERFLOW at 0x00007FFE51D0195D
2015-11-10 00:23:19.41 spid7s      SqlDumpExceptionHandler: Address=0x00007FFE51D0195D Exception Code = c00000fd
2015-11-10 00:23:19.41 spid7s      Rax=00000000000010f8 Rbx=0000000000004000 Rcx=00000000f194ab80 Rdx=00000000ee069000
2015-11-10 00:23:19.41 spid7s      Rsi=0000000000000000 Rdi=00000000ee069000 Rip=0000000051d0195d Rsp=000000004fe02c90
2015-11-10 00:23:19.41 spid7s      Rbp=000000004fe01cb0 EFlags=0000000000010206
2015-11-10 00:23:19.41 spid7s      cs=0000000000000033 ss=000000000000002b ds=000000000000002b
es=000000000000002b fs=0000000000000053 gs=000000000000002b
2015-11-10 00:23:19.41 spid7s      
2015-11-10 00:23:19.41 spid7s      TotalPhysicalMemory = 3220754432, AvailablePhysicalMemory = 1629663232
2015-11-10 00:23:19.41 spid7s      AvailableVirtualMemory = 140733970305024, AvailablePagingFile = 1919029248
2015-11-10 00:23:19.41 spid7s      Stack Signature for the dump is 0x0000000000000000
2015-11-10 00:23:19.42 Server      CLR version v4.0.30319 loaded.
2015-11-10 00:23:19.49 spid7s      External dump process return code 0x20000011.
Error - Failed while writing mini dump.

2015-11-10 00:23:19.56 spid7s      SQL Server shutdown has been initiated
```

One more log...

```
2015-11-09 11:14:41.26 Server      Microsoft SQL Server 2014 - 12.0.4100.1 (X64) 
        Apr 20 2015 17:29:27 
        Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation
        Standard Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.3 <X64> (Build 9600: ) (Hypervisor)

2015-11-09 11:14:41.27 Server      UTC adjustment: 2:00
2015-11-09 11:14:41.27 Server      (c) Microsoft Corporation.
2015-11-09 11:14:41.27 Server      All rights reserved.
2015-11-09 11:14:41.27 Server      Server process ID is 2376.
2015-11-09 11:14:41.27 Server      System Manufacturer: 'VMware, Inc.', System Model: 'VMware Virtual Platform'.
2015-11-09 11:14:41.27 Server      Authentication mode is WINDOWS-ONLY.
2015-11-09 11:14:41.27 Server      Logging SQL Server messages in file 'M:\MSSQL12.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Log\ERRORLOG'.
2015-11-09 11:14:41.27 Server      The service account is 'ST1\Administrator'. This is an informational message; no user action is required.
2015-11-09 11:14:41.27 Server      Registry startup parameters: 
     -d M:\MSSQL12.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\master.mdf
     -e M:\MSSQL12.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Log\ERRORLOG
     -l M:\MSSQL12.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\mastlog.ldf
2015-11-09 11:14:41.27 Server      Command Line Startup Parameters:
     -s "MSSQLSERVER"
2015-11-09 11:14:41.67 Server      SQL Server detected 2 sockets with 1 cores per socket and 1 logical processors per socket, 2 total logical processors; using 2 logical processors based on SQL Server licensing. This is an informational message; no user action is required.
2015-11-09 11:14:41.67 Server      SQL Server is starting at normal priority base (=7). This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
2015-11-09 11:14:41.67 Server      Detected 3071 MB of RAM. This is an informational message; no user action is required.
2015-11-09 11:14:41.68 Server      Using conventional memory in the memory manager.
2015-11-09 11:14:41.79 Server      Default collation: SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS (us_english 1033)
2015-11-09 11:14:43.13 Server      This instance of SQL Server last reported using a process ID of 492 at 11/9/2015 11:08:03 AM (local) 11/9/2015 9:08:03 AM (UTC). This is an informational message only; no user action is required.
2015-11-09 11:14:43.15 Server      Node configuration: node 0: CPU mask: 0x0000000000000003:0 Active CPU mask: 0x0000000000000003:0. This message provides a description of the NUMA configuration for this computer. This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
2015-11-09 11:14:43.64 Server      The maximum number of dedicated administrator connections for this instance is '1'
2015-11-09 11:14:44.19 Server      Using dynamic lock allocation.  Initial allocation of 2500 Lock blocks and 5000 Lock Owner blocks per node.  This is an informational message only.  No user action is required.
2015-11-09 11:14:44.43 Server      CLR version v4.0.30319 loaded.
2015-11-09 11:14:45.01 spid7s      Starting up database 'master'.
2015-11-09 11:14:45.18 spid7s      There have been 256 misaligned log IOs which required falling back to synchronous IO.  The current IO is on file M:\MSSQL12.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\master.mdf.
2015-11-09 11:14:45.68 spid7s      Unable to create stack dump file due to stack shortage (ex_terminator - Last chance exception handling)
2015-11-09 11:14:45.68 spid7s      Stack Signature for the dump is 0x0000000000000000
2015-11-09 11:14:46.27 Server      Common language runtime (CLR) functionality initialized using CLR version v4.0.30319 from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\.
2015-11-09 11:14:46.41 Server      Software Usage Metrics is enabled.
2015-11-09 11:14:47.78 spid7s      External dump process return code 0x20000001.
External dump process returned no errors.
```

Comment: Did you find a solution for this issue. i have exactly the same issue when installing SQL Server 2016 on fail over cluster ?

Answer (score 3):

> Wait on the Database Engine recovery handle failed. Check the SQL Server error log for potential causes.

**What this error means**

This message means SQL Server is installed on your machine but when it is trying to come online it failed. And the reason for the failure would be located at SQL Server [errorlog file](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187885%28v=sql.105%29.aspx). Open the content of file in notepad and post its content in the question. This would tell you `exact reason` why SQL Server is not able to come online

**Workaround:**

You should go to SQl Server configuration manager and locate SQL Server service. Change SQL Server service account to Local System and start SQL Server service. You may or may not succeed.Complete troubleshooting steps are documented in [Could not find Database engine startup handle](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/24364.sql-server-troubleshooting-could-not-find-database-engine-startup-handle-error-during-installation.aspx). If this does not work. Post content of errorlog file as suggested above. The contents would tell us what stopped SQl Server from coming online.

**Note:**
Its not a good security practice to run SQL Server service account via `local system`. After you are done with cluster installation. Create a domain account and change the service account with this domain account. This domain account will have least privileges as documented [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143504.aspx)